# How to define \sc in TeX?

Tags: fonts, plain-tex, small-caps

Taking inspiration from the TeXbook (page 350) I defined:

```
\font\tensc=eccc1000
\font\twelvesc=eccc1200
```

For example, the following works as expected:

```
\font\tensc=eccc1000
\centerline{Donald {\tensc Knuth}}
\bye
```

But I want to define a more general `\sc` that behaves like `\rm`, `\bf`, etc. and I don't know how to do that.

```
\def\sc{something}
\centerline{Donald {\sc Knuth}}
\bye
```

In `plain.tex` there are:

```
\def\rm{\fam\z@\tenrm}
\def\bf{\fam\bffam\tenbf}
```

But I thought font families were only for math mode?
I am a bit lost with `\newfam`, `\textfont`, etc.

Comment: Perhaps provide a minimal working example (MWE) that is a complete TeX document. It could have a few lines, some of which work, some of which (with comments) do not. If you have a particular expectation of what the result should be, then you can attach a screenshot (even if not made by TeX). Also: Is there any particular reason why you are working directly with low-level TeX commands?

Comment: @rallg Well the snippet I provided in a complete TeX document so I am not sure what you are talking about

Comment: OK, but sometimes problems are not caused by the code exhibited, but rather by something else that was not shown.

Comment: @rallg Is there anything unclear about what I'm asking? Basically I've define \tensc and \twelvesc as in the TeXbook but from here I don't know how to define \sc. You know when switching to bold you type \bf rather than \tenbf or something, without having to specify the exact font size

Comment: in plain tex `\rm` selects 10pt roman, in text, and as you comment, math. So are you asking for a `\sc` that works like `\rm` so works in math, or are you asking for an `\sc` that (unlike `\rm`) switches between different sizes?

Comment: `\bf` always selects 10pt bold, so "without having to specify the exact font size" is not really an accurate description.

Comment: Beware that accents are in different position in T1 encoded fonts such as `eccc1000`, so you may need to adjust them, if you use accented letters.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sorry, but if you insist in using plain TeX, you'll get into troubles with this font.

```
\font\tensc=eccc1000

{\tensc \'a\`a\"u\c{a}\={a}\d{a}}

\bye
```

[image]

Oops! What happened? The EC fonts are encoded differently from Knuth's ones, in particular the accents are not in the same places.

You need to switch everything to EC fonts and to redefine all the accent commands.

There *is* a caps and small caps font in the Computer Modern family, namely `cmcsc10` (no optical sizes in the original Knuth distribution, but the AMS has provided `cmcsc8` and `cmcsc9`).

```
\font\tensc=cmcsc10

{\tensc \'a\`a\"u\c{a}\={a}\d{a}}

{\tensc Test With Caps}

\bye
```

You don't probably want to set up math fonts with this shape, so `\newfam` is not needed.

You can also do `\def\sc{\tensc}`, if you like to use less keystrokes.

---

#### Edit after comments.

For XeTeX, you should use OpenType fonts. Not only for smallcaps.

```
\font\tensc=[lmromancaps10-regular.otf]

{\tensc áàüçāạ}

{\tensc Test With Caps}

\bye
```

[image]

#### Why you shouldn't use EC fonts with XeTeX?

```
\font\tenscOT=[lmromancaps10-regular.otf]
\font\tenscL=eccc1000

With legacy {\tt eccc1000} font

{\tenscL ĀĂĄĆČĎĚĘǦĹĽŁŃŇŊOŐŔRRŘSŚSŠŞTŤŢŰŸŹZŽŻŻİ}

{\tenscL ÀÁAÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖŒØÙÚÛÜÝÞ}

\bigskip

With OpenType

{\tenscOT ĀĂĄĆČĎĚĘǦĹĽŁŃŇŊOŐŔRRŘSŚSŠŞTŤŢŰŸŹZŽŻŻİ}

{\tenscOT ÀÁAÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖŒØÙÚÛÜÝÞ}

\bye
```

[image]

Comment: Thank for the warning. I am actually using XeTeX with unicode encoding and {\tensc àüç} works like a charm

Comment: @user989070 And so, why not telling it at the outset? You want to use an OpenType font, then.

Comment: Eh? I am very pleased with campa's answer, it just works, and I have no idea what OpenType is. Sorry if I'm missing something

Comment: @user989070 you should not use the ec fonts with xetex

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I am curious to know why, I've asked a different question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/676319/why-should-i-not-use-ec-fonts-with-xetex Thanks

Comment: @egreg Very clear comparison, thank you