# Why should I not use EC fonts with XeTeX?

Tags: fonts, xetex, plain-tex

In the comments on a question I asked earlier today [How to define \sc in TeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/676277/how-to-define-sc-in-tex/676311), two users said it is not a good idea to use the ec fonts with plain XeTeX.

I am curious to know why since I have been using them for quite some time with no issue.

Example (which seems fine to me):

```
\font\tenrm=ecrm1000 \def\rm{\tenrm}
\rm

éducation % French
virtù % Italian
Constitución % Spanish
\bye
```

Comment: Try `Grüße` and see ...

Comment: well you miss german ;-). Try `Grüße`.

Comment: @JosephWright Okay, so there is a problem with SS, good to know

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The encoding is wrong for plain tex so you will get incorrect characters for example

```
\font\tenrm=ecrm1000 \def\rm{\tenrm}
\rm

éducation % French
virtù % Italian
Constitución % Spanish
Fuß % German


\bye
```

[image]

hyphenation is also wrong with the ec fonts and the default cm fonts as the format is built loading Unicode encoded patterns.

Comment: I rarely type in German so I did not notice that. Thanks

Comment: @user989070 German is really only the start. accent commands are wrong, hyphenation is wrong etc. `plain` is really just an example format for 7-bit fonts for the texbook, it's not set up for other encodings,

Comment: Fuß is so short and ungerman ;-) Fußnotenverwaltungsprogramm?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer ec fonts save the day and make it longer

Answer (score 6):

XeTeX and LuaTeX read Unicode input (files in UTF8) and works internally in Unicode. I.e. it expects Unicode fonts, it loads hyphenation patterns in Unicode.

The EC fonts were designed immediately after T1 encoding was agreed in Cork in 1992. Back then, there was no Unicode aware TeX and the T1 encoding was designed as 8bit (265 characters in single font). It respects ASCII encoding (English and typical non-alphabet characters) and ISO-8859-1 (west European countries, accents, but not German ß). The remaining slots in T1 encoding  were occupied by characters from eastern European countries with Latin accented characters. These remaining slots were set haphazardly, no encoding standard was used.

Unicode respects ASCII encoding + iso-8859 in its first 256 slots. This is reason why almost all accented characters (á, é, etc.) from west European countries (iso-8859-1) works in XeTeX (Unicode). But not all (German ß) and, of course, the characters used by eastern European countries (č, ř, ž, etc.) don't work.

Best solution is using Unicode fonts if you have Unicode aware TeX. Don't read old manuals written in pre-Unicode epoch, don't use incompatible and ancient T1 encoding.

Comment: Actually, there was barely any useful Unicode in 1992.  The Unicode organization was founded in 1988, incorporated in 1991, and joined forces with ISO 19646 in 1992.  But math symbols were pretty sparse until the STIX infusion with Unicode 4.0 in 2003.  XeTeX itself didn't exist until 2005.  But none of that implies that "modern" versions shouldn't be used for current work.